# Query through HABTM with an exact set

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

In Rails 4, I have a vanilla `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, say between `Car`s and `Color`s.

Given a set of `colors` I'd like to find the cars that have exactly those colors. The closest I can get is: `Car.joins(:colors).where('colors.id' => colors)`, but that returns all `Car`s with any of the colors.

I'd like to do this entirely in ActiveRecord since both tables are liable to be huge, so something like `Car.joins(:colors).where('colors.id' => colors).to_a.select{|car| car.colors == colors}` is less than ideal.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it with `having` and some gnarly string interpolated SQL. I've made this into a scope you can use like so:

```
# Car.with_exact(colors: colors)

class ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def with_exact(associations={})
      scope = self
      associations.each do |association_name, set|
        association = reflect_on_association(association_name)
        scope = scope.joins(association_name)
          .group("#{table_name}.id")
          .having("COUNT(\"#{association.join_table}\".*) = ?", set.count)
          .having(%{
            COUNT(\"#{association.join_table}\".*) = SUM(
              CASE WHEN \"#{association.join_table}\".\"#{association.association_foreign_key}\"
              IN (#{set.to_a.map(&:quoted_id).join(', ')})
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            )
          }.squish)
      end
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: isn't it supposed to be `.having('COUNT(car_colors.*) = ?', colors.count)`? This would mean that the car must be `HAVING` exactly `colors.count` colors